# tinyMCE Local Install does not work with local js file, but OK with remote js file

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

Doing some simple testing of tinyMCE on a local machine.  When I reference the remote tinymce.min.js file, it works fine.  When I reference the downloaded tinymce.min.js file and install onto my local machine, it does not work - text box does not appear, just blank.  My code is a virtual cut/paste of what the tinyMCE website showed as an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--<script src='https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js'></script>-->
  <script src='http://localhost/data/anyCompany/modules/blogs/resources/tinymce.min.js'></script>
  <!--<script src='http://localhost/data/anyCompany/modules/blogs/resources/jquery.tinymce.min.js'></script>-->
  <script>
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#mytextarea'
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TinyMCE Quick Start Guide</h1>
  <form method="post">
    <textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried loading the local **jquery**.tinymce.min.js, but it does not seem to make a difference.

Looking at firefox's web debugger console, it shows the tinymce.min.js file has loaded and I can see the contents.

When I use the remote tinymce.min.js reference and look at the debugger, the file looks somewhat different, but I assume it would be functionally the same (?maybe not??).  However, it does load another file named theme.min.js, which does not appear in the downloaded local file...

So, I find this file, theme.min.js, put it into my local machine, reference it, and it does appear to have loaded per the debugging tool... but still nothing!

Using Xampp/Windows, PHP 5.5.15.

Any insight as to why the remote reference works, but the local does not would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also tried including jquery, but still did not change anything: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: So, I thought I would do something clever - load up the web page using the remote tinymce.min.js reference because it works.  I use the web debugger and copy the js contents into my local tinymce.min.js file, hoping it would work - but it did not.

Comment: Did you download and deploy the entire TinyMCE package to your server?  What errors are happening?

Comment: I have jquery.tinymce.min.js, tinymce.min.js, theme.min.js files only.  The browser shows them loaded.  No errors on the xampp webserver logs regarding this page.  On the Firefox browser, I am getting some errors, but don't quite understand them.  One of them on the debug console/CSS tab shows: `Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped`.

Comment: On the console requests tab, it seems to be complaining about two files not being found, which I am not referencing in my HTML code at all and don't have.  Don't quite understand where these references are coming from.  These files are:  `GET
http://localhost/data/anyCompany/modules/blogs/resources/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css` and `GET
http://localhost/data/anyCompany/modules/blogs/resources/skins/lightgray/content.min.css1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments above I would go to https://www.tinymce.com/download/ and download the product - you appear to not have the complete set of files.

We also have documentation on how to deploy and configure the editor:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/first-steps/

Comment: placed the complete set of files on the server and it seemed to have worked!  So, obviously tinymce requires more than just the tinymce.min.js file, which I thought it did...!